# Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol __main (referred from anon$$obj.o)

Tags: linker, arm

I am trying to compile using ARM Compiler. I wrote a simple program.

Where the C:\Source_Codes\2250_sdk\sdkfiles2delivery.....\arm_rvct22\include\windows\ contains all the include files.

Problem : i m facing some unusual linker error

===========================
main.c: 1 warning, 0 errors
Warning: L6310W: Unable to find ARM libraries.
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol __0printf (referred from main.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol __main (referred from anon$$obj.o).
Finished: 0 information, 1 warning and 2 error messages.

====================================

Please help me in this

Thanks
regards
Sobin Thomas

Comment: It is complaining that it can't find library files, not include files.

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to build a standalone program, or do you want to build a program that runs underneath an operating system?
What is your target platform?

Answer (score 1):

With the Arm compiler setting check the Compiler flags and the Linker flags. Try using --verbose to find which Library is missing. Also check if in case you are using environment variable check if the path is correct.

Primary Reasons for this failure reported.
 1. Library not found or missing or path not correct
 2. Compiling of c code as C++ results in symbol not found, identify the API and try using

```
 extern c{};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `.c` file to project: e. g. if you're working on timers, add `stm32f4xx_tim.c` to `User` folder and add it to your project directory.